# Python global variable on __main__

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, global

since multiprocessing need to be put inside `__main__` in windows, i found out that my global variable is not passed to my function.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Value

def Proses(lines):
    global xyz
    try:
        print(lines)
        print(xyz)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

def counter_handler(args):
    global counter
    counter = args

def Dosomething():
    a = [i for i in range(10)]
    return a


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # i want to share xyz variable
    xyz = Dosomething()

    threads = []
    data = ["bjir", "bjir", "bjir"]
    counter = Value('i', 0)
    with Pool(1) as pool:
        p = Pool(1, initializer=counter_handler, initargs=(counter,))
        i = p.map_async(Proses, data, chunksize=1)
        i.wait()
```

been searching for hours but still no clue and i think maybe this is a duplcate quetions and i know it but i still can't find any answers. Is there any way to pass my `xyz` variable to my function?

Comment: If you move that `xyz = Dosomething()` line out before the `if` statement, then it will work.  They aren't shared -- each process will have its own copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have written in your example, `Pool` has `initializer=` and `initargs=` parameters which you can use to initialize the global variables as well:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool, Value


def Proses(lines):
    global xyz

    print(lines)
    print(xyz)


def Dosomething():
    a = [i for i in range(10)]
    return a


def init_pool(a, cnt):
    global xyz, counter
    xyz = a
    counter = cnt


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # i want to share xyz variable
    xyz = Dosomething()

    data = ["bjir", "bjir", "bjir"]
    counter = Value("i", 0)

    with Pool(1, initializer=init_pool, initargs=(xyz, counter)) as pool:
        i = pool.map_async(Proses, data, chunksize=1)
        i.wait()
```

Prints:

```
bjir
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
bjir
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
bjir
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: i used counter_handler functoin because my program need a counter so i can;t remove that part. i tried passing 2 variable on initargs but it still not defined

Comment: @J.Doe I've updated my answer.